# Проблема с классом SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Проблема заключается в том, что Android Studio для использования объектов SimpleDateFormat требует minAPI 24.

У меня в проекте стоит minAPI 19. Я знаю, что можно изменить minAPI, но проблема в том, что я тестирую все проекты на своем девайсе, т.к. на пк не могу, а у моего девайса API 22.

Есть варианты как мне запустить проект на своем девайсе?

Comment: ```SimpleDataFormat``` добавлен с первой версии API, что вы пытаетесь сделать что у вас появляется это ограничение?

Comment: А Вам действительно нужен этот [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), может хватит и [этого](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?

Comment: используйте класс SimpleDateFormat из пакeта java.text., а не фреймворка андроид android.icu.text

Comment: Сейчас опробую.